# How to programmatically select a row in Ui.grid angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have an issue let me put it simple in my plunker example I want to know why is my `$scope.revertSelection()` function not working.
http://plnkr.co/edit/3KXrUuCsSACuhefmyzxN?p=info

Steps:

1. Sort right hand grid by Name(descending order)
2. Select 3-4 rows randomly
3. Click 'Copy' button all selected rows are copied into `$scope.retainSelection`
4. Sort right hand grid by Name(Ascending order)
5. Click 'Revert' button (this is not working)

I am expecting all the rows previously selected in step 2) to be selected back which is not happening :-( please help me with the issue.
I googled but could not find any docs of `gridApi.selection` to look for other methods to fulfill my requirement.

Note: I am using Ui.grid not ng-grid

Comment: Hello, did you get this to work?

Answer (score 19):

I should use...

```
$scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);
$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow($scope.gridOptions.data[i]);
```

...instead of...

```
$scope.gridApi.selection.selectRow(i);
```

My friend gave [link to docs](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.selection.api:PublicApi).

Comment: You'll need to call 'modifyRows' first before 'selectRow' `$scope.gridApi.grid.modifyRows($scope.gridOptions.data);` [https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2267](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/issues/2267#issuecomment-128551701)

Comment: I am able to `selectRow` without `modifyRows` in 4.0.6